# Merging 3 different files

Tags: asp.net, file, merge

**Similiar to:**

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/170309/three-way-merge
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/460198/best-free-3-way-merge-tool-for-windows

I am running 2 websites. One is running .net 3.5, the other is not.  On the site that is running 3.5 I also have the older version.  Right now, I am going through the 3.5 and the 2.0 looking at all the differences and trying to decide which are specific to the upgrade, and which are just related to the design content of the site.  I am looking for a way to compare the first site's 2 versions, looking for differences, then applying those differences to where the site1 and site2 are the same.  Does anyone know of any programs/commands in windows/Linux that can do this?  Or should I just continue the manual search (there are over 25,000 differences to check against)?

Answer (score 0):

What you require is a three-way-merge capable program.

Refer to [this existing SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/460198/best-free-3-way-merge-tool-for-windows).

Answer (score 0):

Many diff tools are able to do a three-way merge (merging the changes between two revisions of a file into a third revision). See: [three way merge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/170309/three-way-merge)

Answer (score 0):

Try [Beyond Compare](http://gofrom.us/E6W).